# How to read the object inside a JSON array

Tags: android, json

I have JSON in this format.
I m trying to create serialization class to store the value.

How to read the "personaldata" field?

I am making a separate class PersonalData to read it.
And in my main serialization class I am reading it as

```
List<PersonalData>personalData
```

Is it the right way to do it?
If so, how will I fetch the personal data values?

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "name": 0,
      "age": 1,
      "class": 0,
      // More data here
      "personalData": {
        "isMarried": true,
        "isEligible": false,
        "Indian": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: There are thousands of answers for this problem already. You can use GSON, but first search the web before posting a question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using some parser like `GSON` or `LoganSquare` you can use their annotations and it will be really easy to parse `JSON` directly to your `model`. Otherwise if you are using native JSON API

You can use something like this

```
JSONArray arr=new JSONArray(response);
JSONObject personalData=arr.getJSONObject("personalData");
```

Comment: I am using gson only, i am not able to write model class to store the valeues.i am new to parsing.

Comment: see the above answer of @cricket_007 as he has done the favour of creating models for you. Now you can use GSON g=new GSON();
Results r=g.fromJson(response, Results.class);

Answer (score 0):

> I am making a separate class PersonalData to read it..

Okay, then *that* is how you access it. By getting that object from some parent `Results` object.

For example, given some implementation of the below classes, once you deserialize the JSON, you use `Results.getResults().get(0).getPersonalData();`

```
public class Results {
    ArrayList<ResultData> result;

    // TODO: write getResults()
}
```

```
public class ResultData {
   int name, age, class;
   // Some more data
   PersonalData personalData;

   // TODO: write getPersonalData()
}
```

```
public class PersonalData {
   boolean isMarried, isEligible, Indian;
}
```